# How do I associate my own database with (local)\netsdk in the connection string?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am trying to learn how to program database applications with C#, and I don't know very much about it just yet.   Right now I am trying to develop a very basic database program of my own creation (not just copying an example), and I do not want to use SqlDataAdapter or anything else like that - just the basic stuff, for learning purposes.  I've created a database for the program called DakotasContacts, which I made through Visual C# Express.  Now I'm trying to get the correct connection string.  At present I have:

```
 static string connectionString = @"
        server = (local)\netsdk;
        database = DakotasContacts;
        integrated security = sspi;
        ";
```

That doesn't work very well.  I've also tried setting database to dakotascontacts, with similar results.  However if I set database to northwind or leave it blank, it'll connect just fine.

How can I get that string to work?  Thanks.

Comment: Where and how did you create your database? Is it definitely on the `(local)\netsdk` SQL Server instance?

Comment: A large part of the problem is that I can't figure out how to check on which instance it's been created on, or where the master copy is.  I did, however, create a local copy on the project itself when the IDE asked me about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='Path to Database file .mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

for example

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='"+System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"@\Customer.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() by this u can get the path of the current directory where your program is.